# Why does Linux RT not use semaphores?

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver

While reading[1] through I found the following

"This is done by replacing most kernel spinlocks with mutexes that support priority inheritance, as well as moving all interrupt and software interrupts to kernel threads."

My question is why not semaphores?

https://rt.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/CONFIG_PREEMPT_RT_Patch

Answer (score 2):

Mutexes are binary semaphores, so they are using a semaphore.

Specifically, the purpose of the lock is to ensure mutual exclusion. This means, create a critical section of code that gets executed only by one context at a time. So we want a semaphore that admits only a single contender - this kind of semaphore is a binary semaphore which has a special nick name to denote this kind of use: mutex.

Comment: The other question is that can there be preemption if there is a mutex/ semaphore  held?

Comment: Yes, of course preemption can happen if a mutex is held. In fact, that is the purpose of replacing the spin locks (which in the Linux kernel block preemption) with mutexes - to enable preemption and thus lower the jitter for real time tasks.

Comment: Just found this\n http://www.dilip.nijagal.com/geeky-stuff/45-technical-stuff/64-difference-between-semaphores-and-mutex

Comment: Mutexes are NOT semaphores.. e.g. a sempahore used to notify another task that input is waitin. You can't do that with a mutex.

Answer (score 0):

Also Found the following

Just found this\n http://www.dilip.nijagal.com/geeky-stuff/45-technical-stuff/64-difference-between-semaphores-and-mutex